# Huawei Push Kit - com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 6003: certificate fingerprint error

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I received a "push token failed, com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 6003: certificate fingerprint error." I don't know what's going on here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your keystore signing configuration in the app-level build.gradle file. You need to make sure that the debug and release signing configs are configured properly.

```
signingConfigs {

   debug {
       storeFile file(DEBUG_STORE_FILE)
       storePassword DEBUG_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS
       keyPassword DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD
   }

   release {
       storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
       storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
       keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
   }
}

buildTypes {
    
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```